# Understanding Python - Variable Defined Outside Function, But Changed Inside Function with no return

Tags: python, function, recursion, quicksort

I recently came across the QuickSort algorithm and found an example for it in Python on Geeksforgeeks here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-quicksort/

My question is this: the variable arr is defined outside of the function Quicksort.. so how is the variable known both in and out of the function without global or return?

Sorry if this was basically posted elsewhere or if posting other people's code is a no-no. Not trying to claim this as mine, I just haven't seen Python code do this before. It's not the algorithm itself nor the use of recursive functions.. it's the lack of global or return that confuses me.

```
def Partition(arr, low, high):
    i= low - 1
    pivot= arr[high]
    
    for j in range(low, high):
        
        if arr[j] <= pivot:
            i += 1
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
            
    arr[i+1], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i+1]
    return i+1



def QuickSort(arr, low, high):
    
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    
    if low < high:
        
        pi= Partition(arr, low, high)
        
        QuickSort(arr, low, pi-1)
        QuickSort(arr, pi+1, high)
            
            
            
arr = [10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5]
n= len(arr)
QuickSort(arr, 0, n-1)
print("Sorted array is:")
for i in range(n):
    print("%d" % arr[i])
```

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: In your own words, what do you think the line of code `QuickSort(arr, 0, n-1)` near the bottom does? In particular, what do you think is the effect of having `arr` as the first thing inside the parentheses?

Comment: Aha that makes sense! It's tough to explain in these little paragraphs. So kudos to you guys. "arr" is assigned to a list object. Since it's mutable, setting another variable to to "arr" binds them to the same object and that same object changes regardless of which name is used. Let's say I have a friend Arianna. I call her "Arr" for short. She moves away for a bit and her new friends also call her "Arr". She, the person, is who changes and grows over time. We lose touch, and I don't know her friends also call her "Arr". She moves back, is a different person, but still called "Arr"

Comment: Hopefully that "Arr" story comes across well!

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is being passed in as an argument here. It is misleading because the variable name in the function is the same as the global one, though it doesn't need to be. For instance, the following code is the same as what you posted:

```py
def Partition(mylst, low, high):
    i= low - 1
    pivot= mylst[high]
    
    for j in range(low, high):
        
        if mylst[j] <= pivot:
            i += 1
            mylst[i], mylst[j] = mylst[j], mylst[i]
            
    mylst[i+1], mylst[high] = mylst[high], mylst[i+1]
    return i+1



def QuickSort(mylst, low, high):
    
    if len(mylst) == 1:
        return mylst
    
    if low < high:
        
        pi= Partition(mylst, low, high)
        
        QuickSort(mylst, low, pi-1)
        QuickSort(mylst, pi+1, high)
            
            
            
arr = [10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5]
n= len(arr)
QuickSort(arr, 0, n-1)
print("Sorted array is:")
for i in range(n):
    print("%d" % arr[i])
```

Even aside from that, as long as you are not changing what a variable is, you can still modify global values in Python. The distinction here is that you're not changing the value of `arr`, but the value of the actual array it is pointing to, so even if you wanted to modify the global array you would not need the global keyword.

Stuff like this is usually not done often in practice so don't worry too much about it. In this scenario at least, the array is being passed into the function, and the Quicksort function directly modifies the array that is passed into it (and it just so happens to be `arr` in this example).

Comment: So in your example, in the print statement at the end, would that also print a changed value from the initial array defined? Are we basically talking pointers? Maybe I just need to read up more on my own. It seemed like a peculiar problem so I figured at the very least it might help someone else out there to post this question. Thanks for the quick and detailed response!

Comment: @Shane variables are references to objects. Python is not like C at all, if that's the background you are coming from. You can *think* of it like everything is a pointer that gets automatically dereferenced for you, but python doesn't have pointers as part of the language per se.